# Parsing a xml file in afnetworking and retrieve data doesn't work

Tags: xml-parsing, afnetworking

With this url I tried but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me to give simple xml parsing code and retrive data from this url?

http://dynamic.feedsportal.com/pf/555218/http://toi.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms

I tried but only reached at

```
NSData * data1 = (NSData *)responseObject;
NSString *fetchedXML = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data1 bytes]];

NSLog(@" xml data :: %@", fetchedXML);
```

then I can't understand how to get data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSXMLParser` is a standard way to parse xml. I suggest you to use [XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) which is more handy wrapper of `NSXMLParser`.

Comment: you can accept the answer if it was helpful for you